# Windows 10 touchpad Release Drag after Finger Lift

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, windows-10, touchpad

I have a Samsung Laptop with ELAN touchpad.

The only features I like from a touchpad are..

- Tap to Click.
- Double Tap to Right Click.
- Two Finger Scrolling.
- Drag Windows. But Release immediately after finger lift.

My Samsung Pointing Device with Windows 10 has no option to control Release Drag immediately after finger lift. It only has a default of Release Drag after certain timeout like 2 seconds. There are no options. It was very irritating and I'm not used to this kind of behaviour.

BTW, I installed its device driver from Windows Update.
If I don't install its device driver, the options that don't work for me are 
`Double Tap To Right Click` and `Two Finger scrolling`.

And if I install this device driver from Windows Update, the option that doesn't work for me is `Release Dragging of Windows Immediately after Finger Lift`

Previously in Windows 7, 8, 8.1 the touchpad settings specifically showed the option "Release Dragging after Finger Lift". But in Windows 10, that option is completely abset.

How can i enable `Tap to Click` , `Double Tap to Right Click` , `Two Finger Scrolling` , `Drag Windows but Release immediatley after Finger Lift` with or without installing any drivers?

Comment: Have you tried going to Samsung, or ELAN to get the latest driver release directly from them? If not, I'd recommend trying that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `Release Dragging of Windows Immediately after Finger Lift` use windows registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad\Drag_Radio`.
Can have next values:

- 0 - tap again to release
- 1 - release after time delay
- 2 - release after finger lift

Comment: Recent update to the elan touchpad driver on windows 10 included the option of 2finger scrolling (reverse and normal) within the interface. That along with this registry tweak solved my issue. `Drag_Radio` as well badly needs to be included in interface. Thanks :)